# selecting Blob column is not using indexes in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, select, indexing, blob

I am having 6 columns in a table. One column is a BLOB column. If I am using the BLOB column in a select, my query is not using an index.

```
select * 
from ACT_GE_BYTEARRAY 
where DEPLOYMENT_ID_ =1234  
order by NAME_ asc
```

Could you please help in this ?

Is there any way to improve without using Oracle Text concepts of creating Domain Index on BLOB column ?

This is plan of the query:

```
SELECT STATEMENT  ALL_ROWSCost: 564  Bytes: 57,247  Cardinality: 23          
    2 SORT ORDER BY  Cost: 564  Bytes: 57,247  Cardinality: 23      
        1 TABLE ACCESS FULL TABLE ACTIVITI.ACT_GE_BYTEARRAY_TEST Cost: 563  Bytes: 57,247  Cardinality: 23
```

---

Yes deplyment_id_ is having index.

```
SELECT STATEMENT ALL_ROWSCost: 242 Bytes: 595 Cardinality: 5 
    3 SORT ORDER BY Cost: 242 Bytes: 595 Cardinality: 5 
        2 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID TABLE ACTIVITI.ACT_GE_BYTEARRAY Cost: 241 Bytes: 595 Cardinality: 5 
            1 INDEX FULL SCAN INDEX ACTIVITI.IDX_COMP_ACGEBYTEARAY Cost: 223 Cardinality: 58
```

Comment: How large is the table?  Perhaps the BLOBs are so big that Oracle decides that reading the table isn't such a big deal after all.

Comment: Table is having 2.5 lakh records. Selecting Blob is going for full table access. Not using any indexes

Comment: It's probably because the available indexes on the table don't look like they will provide any significant benefit to running your query. Is there an index on `DEPLOYMENT_ID_`? What is the plan for a query that uses the index (e.g. `SELECT /*+INDEX(ACT_GE_BYTEARRAY)*/ * from ACT_GE_BYTEARRAY where DEPLOYMENT_ID_ =1234 order by NAME_ asc`)

Comment: Yes deplyment_id_ is having index.                                        SELECT STATEMENT  ALL_ROWSCost: 242  Bytes: 595  Cardinality: 5              
    3 SORT ORDER BY  Cost: 242  Bytes: 595  Cardinality: 5          
        2 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID TABLE ACTIVITI.ACT_GE_BYTEARRAY Cost: 241  Bytes: 595  Cardinality: 5      
            1 INDEX FULL SCAN INDEX ACTIVITI.IDX_COMP_ACGEBYTEARAY Cost: 223  Cardinality: 58